# Compare Mysql Procedure and SQL Server Procedure Performance

Tags: mysql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, benchmarking

Has someone compared performance of similar moderate complexity stored procedures for mysql and MSSQL. We have couple of big proc which we had migrated to Mysql. Those are Running rather slow compared to mssql counter parts.
There can be many reasons

1. Hardware is poor. (RAM, DISK, SSD)
2. Mysql Server Configuration is Improper.
3. Mysql Proc execution and optimizations are really slow.

MSsql database proc is faster by a factor or 2-3 times. For example a proc with 1000 lines take 2 seconds in MSSql and 10 seconds in mysql. 
Can you help me out why? We have done 1 to 1 conversion of proc source code.

Thanks

Comment: First, confirm that it is the SP that makes it slower, not queries, indexes, etc.  `CURSORs` are a big suspect.  So are transactions.  And, who did the translation - something automated, or some novice in MySQL, or an expert in MySQL but who may not understand Mssql subtleties?

Comment: "1 to 1 conversion" could be especially bad when trying to exactly replicate `TOP`, `SEQUENCE`, `ROW_NUMBER`, etc.  Such things are better done by understanding the _intent_ of the code, then implementing the _equivalent_ functionality.

Comment: @RickJames thats what were doing for past 3 months. But Right now I am tweaking mysql config file. Lets see how the performance goes. 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures will give you a small performance boost, but mostly they are for doing tasks that are difficult or impossible to do with a simple query. Stored procedures are great for simplifying access to data for many different types of clients. Database administrators love them because they control how the database is used as opposed to leaving those details to the developer.

Look to indexes and proper table design to get better performance.

Comment: MSsql database proc is faster by a factor or 2-3 times. For example a proc with 1000 lines take 2 seconds in MSSql and 10 seconds in mysql. Can you help me out why? 
We have done 1 to 1 conversion of proc source code.